# Can we use lower version of pay pal sdk with latest xcode and swift version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paypal

I am using Xcode 10.2.1 and swift version 4, now can i integrate paypal payment gateway with older version which is PayPal-iOS-SDK 2.18.1, i am new to payment gateway integration so, any help can be appreciated.

Comment: The first step would be to check the PayPal documentation, have you done that?

Comment: Yes, but in PayPal documentation they are referring to latest versions of paypal sdk's, in my condition i wanted to use older version because some server side code issues

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please note that PayPal mobile SDKs are deprecated ,reference - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDKi. If its new integration suggest you to choose the suitable method for integration than the deprecated one.

Comment: Hi Vidya, thank you, will app store supports deprecated versions of PayPal?

Comment: Yes App store supports , the deprecation is from PayPal that deprecated versions/SDK will no longer be supported for new Integration and hence no updates.